# "Failed to load alembic" Unity3D after build

Tags: unity-game-engine, alembic-format

Facing difficulties with alembic after building for x86_x64 windows.
Alembic files aren't being loaded or read and I am getting this error in the log file

I am using unity 2019.4.16f1
and tried with both Alembic packages 1.0.7(verified with my unity version they say) and 2.1.2

Anyone can help me with this?

> failed to load alembic at C:/Unity Projects/TD_Project/Builds/PC/TD_Project_Data/StreamingAssets\Assets/TD_Project/Models/Towers/Bomb Turret/Models (Animated)/Bomb turret 3rd animation.ABC
> 0x00007FF92D401D1C (UnityPlayer)
> 0x00007FF92D405519 (UnityPlayer)
> 0x00007FF92D3EC3D8 (UnityPlayer)
> 0x00007FF92E6A85AD (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
> 0x00007FF92DF4F45A (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
> 0x0000024BFBB0874D (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.LogOption,string,UnityEngine.Object)
> 0x0000024BFBB0806B (Mono JIT Code) [DebugLogHandler.cs:9] UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
> 0x0000024BFBB07556 (Mono JIT Code) [Logger.cs:60] UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
> 0x0000024C0C2958F2 (Mono JIT Code) [Debug.bindings.cs:127] UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
> 0x0000024BFBFFC1DB (Mono JIT Code) [AlembicStream.cs:149] UnityEngine.Formats.Alembic.Importer.AlembicStream:AbcLoad (bool,bool)
> 0x0000024BFBFF8BFB (Mono JIT Code) [AlembicStreamPlayer.cs:75] UnityEngine.Formats.Alembic.Importer.AlembicStreamPlayer:LoadStream (bool)
> 0x0000024BFC1AACA3 (Mono JIT Code) [AlembicStreamPlayer.cs:117] UnityEngine.Formats.Alembic.Importer.AlembicStreamPlayer:Update ()
> 0x0000024BBF165B38 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
> 0x00007FF92C6ED6D0 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_get_runtime_build_info
> 0x00007FF92C672932 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_perfcounters_init
> 0x00007FF92C67B98F (mono-2.0-bdwgc) mono_runtime_invoke
> 0x00007FF92DEBA82D (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
> 0x00007FF92DEB74BD (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
> 0x00007FF92DE9A8A3 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
> 0x00007FF92DE9A95D (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
> 0x00007FF92D878D80 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
> 0x00007FF92D87FCFD (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
> 0x00007FF92DB4F5DB (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
> 0x00007FF92DB3D6D7 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
> 0x00007FF92DB3D79F (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
> 0x00007FF92DB4138D (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
> 0x00007FF92D42CF2B (UnityPlayer)
> 0x00007FF92D42B87A (UnityPlayer)
> 0x00007FF92D430096 (UnityPlayer)
> 0x00007FF92D433DCB (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
> 0x00007FF6501A11F2 (TD_Project)
> 0x00007FF9A6CA7C24 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
> 0x00007FF9A6E6D4D1 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
> (Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently alembics are streaming assets and need to be in the "StreamingAssets" folder in the build directory. Unity automatically does this if the asset is in the scene if not you have to manually copy the files to the proper directory.

You can use Johansski's code to do the copying from the editor instead of the filesystem manually. Johanski discusses this at this Unity forum where a similar question was asked:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/missing-alembic-streaming-assets.635320/#post-4776968